# Javascript Array Length Behavior

Tags: javascript

Let `arr = [1,2,3,4]`. If I set `arr[x]` where `x >= arr.length`, `arr.length` becomes `x + 1`.

This happens on Firefox and Chrome. I have two questions:

1. Is this defined behavior? (source would be welcome)
2. Is doing this recommended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this defined behavior?

Yes, see [§15.4 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4).

> Is doing this recommended?

It depends entirely on what end result you want. There's nothing wrong with doing it.

You'll quite commonly see arrays built up like this:

```
var a = [];
for (/*...some loop over things...*/) {
    a[a.length] = /* ...something to put on the array... */;
}
```

...which is exactly the same as:

```
var a = [];
for (/*...some loop over things...*/) {
    a.push(/* ...something to put on the array... */);
}
```

Some JavaScript engines process the `a[a.length] = ...` faster than the `a.push(...)` (others are the opposite).

Note that JavaScript arrays are *sparse*, they can have gaps in them, which is part of the reason for this behavior. (In fact, JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).) You can assign assign to the `length` property.

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't sure whether this is behavior I can depend on (whether it would work in IE) and whether it could change in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes start from zero.

```
arr[0] == 1
arr[1] == 2
arr[2] == 3
arr[3] == 4
```

When you set `arr[4]`, it becomes the 5th element.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could do this in JavaScript.

- The array will extend to the xth index, and place your value there.
- The length of the array will be x+1.
- The values in the indexes in between that were never defined, 4 to x-1 in your case, will be `undefined`.